# What is the set describing a unit sphere?

Tags: geometry

I want to define a set $S$ where $S$ is the surface of a unit sphere with diameter running from (0,0,0) to (0,0,1) on the z axis, in (x,y,z) coordinates. For example $S=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R^3}\mid x^2+y^2+z^2=1\}$. Obviously this sphere is wrong because (0,0,0) is not contained on its surface.

Comment: There is only one unit sphere, and it's the one you have written the set description for. There are many other spheres, such as the one you want to find the description for, but none of those are called "unit".

Comment: There is no sphere of unit radius with diameter running from $(0,0,0)$ to $(0,0,1)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general description of a sphere with center $(a,b,c)$ and radius $r$ is
$$
\{(x,y,z)\in \Bbb R^3\mid (x-a)^2+(y-b)^2+(z-c)^2=r^2\}
$$
The description comes directly from the Pythagorean theorem, stating that "the distance from $(a,b,c)$ to $(x,y,z)$ is $r$". Now you just need to figure out the center and radius of your sphere and insert that into the above description, and you're done.